# Send mouse event to element via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have an element behind another, but it's still visible(its covered only partially by the element itself, but is otherwise completely covered by the margin attribute of the element above). I want to trigger a mouse event when I mouse over, but it doesn't get passed to it because of the element in front. I know how to calculate if I am over it and how to point to it, but I don't know how to send it the event `onmouseover` or `hover` or `onmouseout`.

If it helps I would be pointing at it by using `document.getElementById("<calculated id>")`. I know this works because it's ID is based off of its location within a grid, so I just have to calculate the position of the mouse and relate it to the grid.

Also the event that is supposed to happen(but isn't because of the things in front of it), is a `:hover` that triggers a simple transition animation via CSS.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('elementInFront').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    document.getElementById('elementBehind').DoYourStuff();
});
```

Comment: there are more than one behind the one in front. This would send it to only one of them, and doesn't tell me how to send an event to it that triggers the hover or mouseover even if this would get the element behind it properly. Thanks for the attempt though

Answer (score 1):

Does this work? I'm not sure if I understand your intention.

```
var item = document.getElementById("CalculatedId");
item.addEventListener("mouseover", func, false);

function func()
{  
   console.log("Hovered");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the css property

```
pointer-events: none;
```

On the top element. This will allow all mouse events to "fall-through" to the element in the back. Unfortunately this doesn't work in IE, the only simple alternative for that is to make the front element's background transparent

Comment: Doesn't work in either chrome or firefox. I've tried this before and it is experimental at best. I'm trying to do it in a reliable way that works now, and the only way to apparently do that is by figuring out which one the mouse is over, and forcing an event to be sent through to it, if that can be done, but `pointer-events: none;` doesn't work